# How to show a loader before the page fully loads?

Tags: magento2, loader

I want to show the loader before my website fully load as the customer is trying to click the some of the links before the page gets loaded.

To show the order, where I have to update?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install this module:
https://alothemes.com/magento-lazy-load.html

I hope this will help you.